# copy multiple charts (graphs) from excel and paste in word existing document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-charts

I'm trying to copy multiple charts from excel and paste them on a live-report word based

i have a word report, in which i want to paste charts from excel.
copied the code and added the strfile row. getting errors. HELP

```
Sub ExportingToWord_MultipleCharts_Worksheet()

    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim SecCnt As Integer
    Dim strFile As String
    
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    'Create a new instance of Word
    'Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
        'WrdApp.Visible = True
        'WrdApp.Activate
  
    strFile = "C:\Users\path\file.docx"
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wordapp.Documents.Open strFile
    wordapp.Visible = True
    WrdApp.Activate
    
    
    
    'Loop through the charts on the active sheet
    For Each ChrtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    
        'Copy the chart
        ChrtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

        'Paste the Chart in the Word Document
        With WrdApp.Selection
            .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine
        End With
        
        'Count the pages in the Word Document
        SecCnt = WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
        
        'Add a new page to the document.
         WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add

        'Go to the newly created page.
        WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
        
    Next ChrtObj

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you copy the code from? Did that code originally work? What did you change? Show the errors you get.

Comment: Any reason you mix early and late binding?

Comment: Your code is inconsistent as it uses a mix of `WrdApp` and `wordapp` to refer to the Word Application. Fix that and then see if you still have issues.

Comment: `Option Explicit` would save you from these types of errors.

Comment: err91: Object variable or with block vriable not set (fixed the WrdApp  and wordapp syntax)